# How to collect panic! argument?

Tags: rust

How can I collect `panic!(arg)`'s `arg` after it was emitted? [This](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.panic!.html) documentation is not clear.

When doing `panic!(42)` I want my application to collect the 42 and fail gracefully instead of just aborting.

Comment: If the `panic!` is in code you control... I believe, in general, the recommendation is to use [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) and return an `Err(arg)` instead of panicking if you want to respond to it.

Comment: I understand but still I would like to "collect" the value as it says it is possible.

Comment: [`catch_unwind()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.catch_unwind.html) (Rust 1.9) would be the starting point to handle an unwinding panic! (excluding any that stop the process immediately). `arg` should be contained in the `Result` it returns.

Comment: Doesn't matter for the case but does it still follow recommendation since it returns `Result`?

Comment: No, it's not recommended to use `catch_unwind` except if you do not have control over the location where the `panic` happens (because someone else wrote bad code) or because you are calling Rust-code from C or other languages' code. If it's because someone else wrote panicky code, you should first try to fix their crate before resorting to `catch_unwind`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To collect the argument, downcast the `Box<Any>` into a concrete type. In your case, I forced 42 to be type `i32`:

```
use std::thread::spawn;

fn main() {
    let thread = spawn(|| { panic!(42_i32); });
    let result = thread.join();
    match result {
        Ok(_) => { println!("thread join result ok"); }
        Err(e) => {
            match e.downcast::<i32>() {
                Ok(e2) => { println!("Got an int error: {:?}", e2); }
                Err(e3) => { println!("Got unknown error: {:?}", e3); }        
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just used `i32` because `Box<Any>` must be downcast to a concrete type and I wasn't sure what the default type from `panic!(42);` would be. Turns out on my computer it is `i32` but then I wondered if it would be so on all architectures. So I just forced 42 to be an `i32`. Based on your question I looked it up and apparently `i32` is [the default type for integers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/primitive-types.html#numeric-types) and so `_i32` shouldn't be necessary on any platform.